# Easily Change A List After THE nth item

Tags: c#, list

I got a list:
`var x = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"}`

I am looking for an pretty easy way to change all items after a
example:

```
var x = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"}
var y = new List<string>(){"d","e","f"}
x.addAfterFirst(y);
```

result `x= "a","d","e","f"`

I know that' x.Skip(1)' can return me the info. I need to set it.

Comment: "Add after first" doesn't match the expected result you provided. Furthermore, there is no `list<T>` class in .NET, only `List<T>`.

Comment: Do you mean to remove the final element of `x` and then append `y` to the end?

Comment: In result x= "a","b","d","e","f" is "c" meant to be left out?

Comment: you mean you want `result` to be `"a", "d", "e", "f"`, right?

Comment: dtbs commet want auccurate, Daniel's petty, Fixed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Take Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to take  the first *n*  items from `x` and concat them with `y` using the [Concat Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
List<string> x = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> y = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };

int n = 1;

List<string> result = x.Take(n).Concat(y).ToList();
// result == { "a", "d", "e", "f" }
```

---

If you want to modify `x` in-place instead of creating a new list, you can use the [RemoveRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) to remove all items after the first *n* items, and the [AddRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) to append `y` to `x`:

```
List<string> x = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> y = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };

int n = 1;

x.RemoveRange(n, x.Count - n);
x.AddRange(y);
// x == { "a", "d", "e", "f" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of InsertRange will do you task

```
var x = new list<string>(){"a","b","c"}
var y = new list<string>(){"d","e","f"}
x.InsertRange(2,y);
```

**Edit**

now if you want to remove element

```
var x = new list<string>(){"a","b","c"};
int xlength = x.Count() - 1;
var y = new list<string>(){"d","e","f"};
int ylength = y.Count() - 1;
x.InsertRange(2,y);
x.RemoveRang( 2 + ylength, xlength- 2);
```

Comment: -1: Read his question again. The result of your code will be `a, d, e, f, b, c`, but he expects `a, d, e, f`.

Answer (score 0):

Your result doesn't match the full description

Are you wishing to insert or replace

Are you needing to modify the existing collection or could you accept a new collection?

All examples use the following initialization

```
var insertIndex=1;
var x = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};
var y = new List<string>(){"d","e","f"};
```

New Collection Replace

```
var result=x.Take(insertIndex).Concat(y).ToList();
```

New Collection Insert

```
var result=x.Take(insertIndex).Concat(y).Concat(x.Skip(insertIndex)).ToList();
```

Modify Collection Replace

```
x.RemoveRange(insertIndex,x.Count-insertIndex);
x.AddRange(y);
```

Modify Collection Insert

```
x.InsertRange(insertIndex,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-LINQ extention way:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i < y.Count;i++) 
{
     if (i+1 < x.Count)
         x[i+1] = y[i];
     else
         x.Add(y[i]); 
 }
 //If you dont want trailing elements to remain in x
 for (;i < x.Count;i++)
     x.RemoveAt(i);
```